# PHP strptime() Doesn't seem to work? I can't see anything wrong

Tags: php, mysql, strptime

I am currently trying to get a database transfered from an old system to a new one, and i have run into a small issue.

I have a db row formatted at:

2007-04-24 00:23:59
(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

And i cant seem to get it to work through strptime()

Here is what i have:

```
$format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s';
$ct = strptime($row['time'], $format );
//$row['time'] == 2007-01-11 00:47:27
```

This returns nothing.

Can anyone see anything wrong with that?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you output it

Comment: The date needs to be a string. Whats inside `$row['time']`?

Comment: This function isn't implemented on Windows so if you're on a Windows platform it won't work. Also from the PHP manual
Note:
Internally, this function calls the strptime() function provided by the system's C library. This function can exhibit noticeably different behaviour across different operating systems. The use of date_parse_from_format(), which does not suffer from these issues, is recommended on PHP 5.3.0 and later.

Comment: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`, you're confusing the `date()` & `strftime()` characters.

Comment: I added a comment below saying what $row['time'] is: //$row['time'] == 2007-01-11 00:47:27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format should be a bit different:

```
$format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'; // or just '%F %T'
```

Here's the corresponding section of `strftime` [**format documentation**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#refsect1-function.strftime-parameters):

```
%M  Two digit representation of the minute  [00 through 59]
%S  Two digit representation of the second  [00 through 59]
%T  Same as "%H:%M:%S"
%F  Same as "%Y-%m-%d" (commonly used in database datestamps)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be this `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s';`

Comment: @Scott `strftime` and `date` formats are different.

Comment: I didnt realize that strftime and date had different codes for the time, thanks for that.  How-ever, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, ending up getting it working with... so apparently i just needed to know that Date and strptime are different formats :P   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the **[strftime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)** documentation for the proper format.

Your foramt should be:

```
$format = '%Y-%m-%d %T';
```

Comment: and even shorter **"%F %T"**

Answer (score 0):

From manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php

```
<?php
$format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S';
$strf = strftime($format);

echo "$strf\n";

print_r(strptime($strf, $format));
?>
```

Result

```
03/10/2004 15:54:19

Array
(
    [tm_sec] => 19
    [tm_min] => 54
    [tm_hour] => 15
    [tm_mday] => 3
    [tm_mon] => 9
    [tm_year] => 104
    [tm_wday] => 0
    [tm_yday] => 276
    [unparsed] =>
)
```

Comment: If you even cannot change date format regarding you need - programming is not for you. Of course it different, it's obvious that you should change it as you need.

Comment: I know that i should change it, im simply stating that when giving answers it might be more clear to represent the answer directly to the question.  I had already read the manual, but i must have missed the formatting thinking it was the same as date format

Answer (score 0):

`strptime()` is not available in Windows.

> Note: This function is not implemented on Windows platforms.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php

Answer (score -1):

This is how I usually handle date formatting.

```
$somedate = strtotime($dateValue);
$formatted_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $somedate);
```

Comment: Good for you, but the question was about something else

Comment: If i could like a comment i would.  Thanks for trying to help though Michael.